# IF in case when mysql

Tags: mysql

assume i have 3 tables

table order

```
+----+-------------+
| id | total_price |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |       50000 |
+----+-------------+
```

table order_detail

```
+----+----------+------------+-----------+
| id | order_id | product_id | bundle_id |
+----+----------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |        1 |         20 |         1 | 
|  2 |        1 |         21 |         1 |  
|  3 |        1 |         22 |         2 |  
|  4 |        1 |         23 |         2 |
|  5 |        1 |         24 |      NULL |      
+----+----------+------------+-----------+
```

table bundle

```
+----+----------+---------+-----------------+
| id | order_id | type_id | discount_amount |
+----+----------+---------+-----------------+
|  1 |        1 |       6 |           23000 |
|  2 |        1 |       6 |           22000 |
|  3 |        1 |       2 |            5000 |
+----+----------+---------+-----------------+
```

with order.id = order_detail.order_id
and order_detail.bundle_id = bundle.id

as our can see, some product_id has same bundling_id, so i want to make this conditions

1. IF type_id != 6 THEN 0 for every product_id
2. IF product_id with type_id != 6 has same bundle_id, then for every product_id with same bundle_id, just appear one discount_amount, and the other filled with '0'

for that conditions i make this query

```
  SELECT od.product_id, 
IF(b.type_id != 6, 0, (this is query case when to condition 2, which i still searching it how to solve it))
    FROM order_discount od JOIN bundle b ON od.bundle_id = b.id
```

EXPECTED RESULTS

```
+------------+-----------------+
| product_id | discount_amount |
+------------+-----------------+
|         20 |           23000 |
|         21 |               0 |
|         22 |           22000 |
|         23 |               0 |
|         24 |               0 |
+------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Please add a fiddle - I know that you know how to do this..

Comment: Both product_is 20 and 21 refers to bundle_id 1. Why it's discount is applied to 20 and not to 21? Both products refers to a bundle with type=6, and hence they does not match your rules 1 and 2.

Comment: whether is 20 or 21 for bundle_id 1, it will appear just once not twice

Comment: Both your rules operates with `IF type_id != 6` condition. All your bundles have `type_id = 6`. So there is no rule for them.

Comment: ok let me edit the table